# SQL query that returns the primary key if found, NULL otherwise

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Given a table like

```
create table foo(id integer primary key, name varchar(128) unique not null);
```

I am looking for a query that searches for a given name, returns the `id` if found, and `NULL` otherwise. Sort of what left join can do, except here there is no left table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation with `MAX()` (or `MIN()`):

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id
FROM foo
WHERE name = ?;
```

An aggregation query like this always returns exactly 1 row with 1 column and if no `name` satisfies the condition in the `WHERE` clause then it returns `NULL`.

Replace `?` with the name that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d5c1b4cb3d98812ba730b0b48aecde76).

Answer (score 0):

Or use `UNION`:

```
(select id 
 from foo
 where name='user1234'
 union 
 select null) 
order by id desc 
limit 1;
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80a07a75392434bc44e5948ca2384404)